# Ubuntu 12, chromium/chrome facebook not loading

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, facebook

this problem started with chrome, tried chromium to fix it. both have this problem, and after installed firefox no longer works with facebook. I found a threas with two fixes that work and what I need to know is how to make these fixes permanent.

one is a cache permissions workaround. launching chromium from terminal with a redirect to a new self created cache in the home folder works. how can i repair the permissions issue with the cache or make a permanent change to the cache chromium uses?

two, the ifconfig wlan0 mtu set to 1492, this setting doesnt seem to be perpetual after a reboot.

this set of issues is I believe specific to my particular install as there isnt a huge issue from anyone else out there, i'm on a toshiba satellite laptop with a 50/50 HDD partition split with windows. This is likely causing the issue or contributing in some way but I wont run linux full time on this machine until I get these kinks a more permanent fix.

Thanks in advance for any advice/answers.

Comment: you should get more precise about what "not loading" means to you. What do you see; what is being displayed? Also: isn't emptying the cache once working? You could open facebook, press [CTRL]+[F5] and see what happens. This would be a much nicer solution than your two.

Comment: i agree it would be nicer, but it doesnt work. the only way to make it work for me has been the above solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I found on way to change the MTU to a more permanent 1492 setting instead of "automatic." It's in **Settings** > **Network** > **`wlan0`**, and change the `mtu` from `auto` to `1492`.

One of two, actually with that change it may just work, as it is now. I'll report back if there are more issues.